# Execution failed for task ':flutter_secure_storage:parseDebugLocalResources'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to run a flutter android code in debug mode, and getting this error.

> Execution failed for task ':flutter_secure_storage:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_secure_storage:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33\android.jar.
> > C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33\android.jar

Can anyone help me on this issue.